# Pandas interpolation creating a horizontal line

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

This is a continuation of the following question:
[Plot a line on a curve that is undersampled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700195/plot-a-line-on-a-curve-that-is-undersampled/73703531#73703531)

I tried the solution provided but with real data and getting a straight line. The full data is pasted below:

```
mdcol, tvdcol = 'md_m', 'tvd_m'
df = df[[mdcol, tvdcol]].copy().set_index(mdcol)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

data_intp = (df.reindex(index = range(int(df.index.min()), int(df.index.max())))
               .reset_index() # optional, you could write 'index' in the second line plot, too.
               .interpolate()
              )
data_intp
```

Dataframe is shown below:

```
md_m    tvd_m
0   0.00    0.00
1   281.00  281.00
2   300.00  300.00
3   330.00  330.00
4   360.00  360.00
5   390.00  390.00
6   420.00  420.00
7   450.00  450.00
8   480.00  480.00
9   510.00  510.00
10  540.00  539.99
11  570.00  569.98
12  600.00  599.97
13  630.00  629.94
14  660.00  659.91
15  690.00  689.88
16  720.00  719.84
17  750.00  749.80
18  780.00  779.75
19  810.00  809.69
20  840.00  839.58
21  870.00  869.34
22  900.00  898.90
23  930.00  928.19
24  950.00  947.55
25  960.00  957.18
26  970.00  966.76
27  980.00  976.32
28  990.00  985.83
29  1000.00 995.32
30  1010.00 1004.77
31  1020.00 1014.20
32  1030.00 1023.60
33  1040.00 1032.96
34  1050.00 1042.29
35  1060.00 1051.56
36  1070.00 1060.78
37  1080.00 1069.94
38  1090.00 1079.05
39  1100.00 1088.11
40  1110.00 1097.12
41  1120.00 1106.10
42  1130.00 1115.03
43  1140.00 1123.91
44  1150.00 1132.73
45  1160.00 1141.48
46  1170.00 1150.17
47  1180.00 1158.80
48  1190.00 1167.37
49  1200.00 1175.86
50  1210.00 1184.28
51  1220.00 1192.61
52  1230.00 1200.88
53  1240.00 1209.09
54  1250.00 1217.24
55  1260.00 1225.36
56  1270.00 1233.50
57  1280.00 1241.70
58  1290.00 1249.95
59  1300.00 1258.22
60  1310.00 1266.50
61  1320.00 1274.79
62  1330.00 1283.11
63  1340.00 1291.46
64  1350.00 1299.84
65  1360.00 1308.23
66  1370.00 1316.64
67  1380.00 1325.08
68  1390.00 1333.55
69  1400.00 1342.05
70  1410.00 1350.59
71  1420.00 1359.16
72  1430.00 1367.75
73  1440.00 1376.37
74  1450.00 1385.00
75  1460.00 1393.65
76  1470.00 1402.31
77  1480.00 1411.01
78  1490.00 1419.75
79  1500.00 1428.51
80  1510.00 1437.30
81  1520.00 1446.11
82  1530.00 1454.92
83  1540.00 1463.71
84  1550.00 1472.46
85  1560.00 1481.20
86  1570.00 1489.93
87  1580.00 1498.65
88  1590.00 1507.37
89  1600.00 1516.09
90  1610.00 1524.84
91  1620.00 1533.62
92  1630.00 1542.40
93  1640.00 1551.18
94  1650.00 1559.96
95  1660.00 1568.74
96  1670.00 1577.53
97  1680.00 1586.29
98  1690.00 1595.01
99  1700.00 1603.69
100 1710.00 1612.36
101 1720.00 1621.02
102 1730.00 1629.66
103 1740.00 1638.27
104 1750.00 1646.84
105 1760.00 1655.35
106 1770.00 1663.83
107 1780.00 1672.27
108 1790.00 1680.65
109 1800.00 1688.97
110 1810.00 1697.23
111 1820.00 1705.42
112 1830.00 1713.54
113 1840.00 1721.60
114 1850.00 1729.61
115 1860.00 1737.63
116 1870.00 1745.66
117 1880.00 1753.69
118 1890.00 1761.72
119 1900.00 1769.70
120 1910.00 1777.61
121 1920.00 1785.44
122 1930.00 1793.20
123 1940.00 1800.86
124 1950.00 1808.43
125 1960.00 1815.92
126 1970.00 1823.31
127 1980.00 1830.62
128 1990.00 1837.83
129 2000.00 1844.95
130 2010.00 1851.96
131 2020.00 1858.89
132 2030.00 1865.76
133 2040.00 1872.58
134 2050.00 1879.35
135 2060.00 1886.05
136 2070.00 1892.70
137 2080.00 1899.28
138 2090.00 1905.78
139 2100.00 1912.20
140 2110.00 1918.50
141 2120.00 1924.66
142 2130.00 1930.68
143 2140.00 1936.57
144 2150.00 1942.34
145 2160.00 1947.97
146 2170.00 1953.47
147 2180.00 1958.83
148 2190.00 1964.06
149 2200.00 1969.16
150 2210.00 1974.12
151 2220.00 1978.93
152 2230.00 1983.63
153 2240.00 1988.25
154 2250.00 1992.78
155 2260.00 1997.23
156 2270.00 2001.60
157 2280.00 2005.87
158 2290.00 2010.06
159 2300.00 2014.15
160 2310.00 2018.12
161 2320.00 2021.97
162 2330.00 2025.68
163 2340.00 2029.25
164 2373.20 2039.67
165 2401.60 2047.31
166 2430.80 2054.90
167 2459.70 2062.45
168 2488.30 2069.84
169 2488.30 2069.88
170 2489.97 2070.30
171 2493.30 2071.11
172 2503.50 2073.51
173 2519.97 2077.32
174 2549.97 2083.99
175 2563.51 2086.88
176 2579.97 2090.18
177 2609.97 2095.34
178 2639.97 2099.36
179 2662.86 2101.68
180 2752.86 2109.47
181 2759.97 2110.08
182 2789.97 2112.33
183 2819.97 2114.10
184 2849.97 2115.39
185 2879.97 2116.19
186 2902.87 2116.48
187 2909.96 2116.53
188 2939.96 2116.72
189 2969.96 2116.92
190 2999.96 2117.11
191 3029.96 2117.31
192 3059.96 2117.51
193 3089.96 2117.70
194 3119.96 2117.90
195 3149.96 2118.09
196 3179.96 2118.29
197 3209.96 2118.49
198 3239.96 2118.68
199 3252.87 2118.76
200 3352.87 2119.41
201 3359.96 2119.45
202 3389.96 2119.65
203 3419.96 2119.84
204 3449.96 2120.04
205 3479.96 2120.23
206 3509.96 2120.43
207 3539.96 2120.62
208 3569.96 2120.82
209 3599.96 2121.01
210 3629.96 2121.21
211 3652.87 2121.35
212 3779.95 2122.17
213 3852.87 2122.64
```

Plotting shows the horizontal line:

```
TOOLS = ["box_zoom", "reset", "save", "crosshair", "pan", "wheel_zoom" ,"lasso_select"]
p = figure(plot_width = 1600, 
           plot_height = 800, tools = TOOLS, 
           title = 'Well Survey', toolbar_location='above')
p.line(data_intp[mdcol], data_intp[tvdcol], line_width = 2, color='red')
show(p)
```

Not sure where the interpolation is going wrong. I was hoping it would interpolate between the points. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer gmerrit123, but I believe I remove that error by using this line:

```
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

What solved it for me was converting the md column to INT, as the reindexing was running with step = 1 meter, but the raw data had 2 decimal points.

```
mdcol, tvdcol = 'md_m', 'tvd_m'
df = data[[mdcol, tvdcol]].copy()#.set_index(mdcol)#.reindex(index = range(int(df.index.min()), int(df.index.max())))
df[mdcol] = df[mdcol].astype('int')
df = df.set_index(mdcol)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

data_intp = (df.reindex(index = range(int(df.index.min()), int(df.index.max()+ 1)))
               .reset_index()
               .interpolate()
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your data (and this proposed solution) is that you have a single duplicate value in md_m:

```
chk = df.groupby('md_m').agg({'tvd_m':['count',lambda x: list(x)]}) 
print(chk[chk['tvd_m']['count']>1])
```

returns:

[image]

Pandas can't "reindex from a duplicate axis" which is what this approach relies on and really, linear interpolation won't really work either when you have two identical x values and two distinct y values.

An extra layer of QA could be done on the input data, inspecting it beforehand like my snippet, and doing a groupby average or something like that if appropriate.

The only other thing I'd point out is using a range (i.e. integers) for the reindexing is kinda unneccessary --> you should be able to reindex with floats to any step size you want.